# Trying to make an app for fitbit

Tags: android, bluetooth, notifications, fitbit

I'm trying to make an android app that'll send my fitbit some custom notifications via bluetooth, for example to print 'Hi' on the fitbit or make it vibrate, but I'm very unfamiliar with this, does anyone have any resources to get me started?

Comment: did you find any solution for this?

Comment: unfortunately no, the bluetooth API/SDK is not available on the fitbit (I messaged fitbit) the closest thing to do would be to have an app that would send yourself a text/notification through some event and then use fitbits built-in notifications to show you the message. The flow would be App->event->SMS->Phone->fitbit (showing you the SMS)

Comment: Actually, I just want to get the health related stuff without using REST api, will that be possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible, however is it efficient? I'd have to say maybe not. If you're trying to do health related things maybe look at the rest APIs and just use them and build your app around that? If not, then you'll have to somehow hack the fitbit's firmware and I don't know enough about that to give advice.